# How can I use python iterable to perform flexible search generators?

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

**EDIT: Turns out this isn't much of a question.  I managed to get this working as I more or less typed this in.**

I've got an online csv table database that I query with a cgi script.  The script can take several optional filter arguments, but adding a new filter means I have to double my `if` statements.

Ex:

```
records = list()
with open (csv_datafile, 'r') as data: 
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames=DATA_FIELDS)
    if product is None:
        records.extend(record for record in data_reader if id_start < record['id'] <= id_end)
    else:
        records.extend(record for record in data_reader if id_start < record['id'] <= id_end and record['code'] == product)
```

You can see, that if I add another search criteria, this pattern falls apart because I'd have to nest redundant if's in each of the above `if` clauses.

Is there a way I use an iterator to do this? My thinking is along the lines of:

```
def data_search(iterator, **search)
    for item in iterable:
        yield_me=True
        for key in item.viewkeys() & search:
            if item[key] is not None:
                if item[key] != search[key]:
                    yeild_me=False
        if yield_me:
            yield item
```

Then the code to integrate would be something like:

```
search = dict()
if product_search:
    search['code'] = product

if vendor_search:
    search['vendor'] = vendor

records = list()
with open (csv_datafile, 'r') as data: 
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames=DATA_FIELDS)
    data_reader = data_search(data_reader, **search)
    records.extend(record for record in data_reader if id_start < record['id'] <= id_end)
```

Should I continue on this tack, or is there a better way?

Comment: Are your filters always looking to match a field of the dictionary against an existing variable?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper If I understand your question, yes.  The search variables are set once at the top of the script.  Currently there's only one field in the dictionary that _could_ be searched, but I'm looking to add more without overly complicating the generator.

Comment: Huh. It turns out this isn't much of question.  The above code works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a generator for this. I think you're on the right track with building up your search conditions (although if you can get them passed in as name/value pairs in a dictionary that's easier to work with), but enforcing it can be simpler.

```
with open(csv_datafile, 'r') as data:
    data_reader = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames=DATA_FIELDS)
    records = [record for record in data_reader if all(record.get(filter_key) == filter_value for (filter_key, filter_value) in search.iteritems()) and id_start < record['id'] <= id_end]
```

There are different expressions possible using `filter` if you prefer, and I might make a `passes_search_filters` helper function for legibility.